# oracle database sandbox

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to create database server "sandbox"?
So there is a master server that contains real data and a sandbox server that should dispatch read request to the master server in case the sandbox does not have cached data.
In the case of a write request it should create a local copy of the data and apply changes to that copy without any impact to the master server.

Answer (score 4):

You could build such a thing.

1. Create a local Oracle database with a database link that points back to the master database.
2. Copy the DDL for every object you're interested in from the master database to your local database renaming each table (i.e. `EMP` becomes `EMP_LOC`).
3. Create a view in the local database for each table that does a `UNION ALL` between the remote and local copies of the table.
4. Create an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the local view that writes any changes only to the local table.

While you could do such a thing, however, it's not obvious why you'd want to.  It would be a fair amount of work to set up and maintain and performance could easily get dodgy rather easily.  And it's not obvious what problem this approach solves-- it wouldn't replace the need to have isolated development, test, and staging environments.  And I'm hard-pressed to come up with a lot of use cases where this sort of "sandbox" would be preferable to one of those environments.

Answer (score 1):

@Justin Cave give a good approach.. however maybe you should consider creating a Virtual Machine and take a snapshot of your PROD instance whenever you want to work on something new with the latest data.

Comment: Unfortunately that database is too big to create its full copy.

Comment: ok - i now think that you are trying to gain performance by replicating a small subset of data somewhere else - sort of on demand.  In this case, my VM suggestion is not appropriate.